# On adding the click event tracker using jquery on the document, the click event on a link is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a file listing and there is option to delete the file. So on clicking the delete it asks for a confirmation. On clicking the confirm the file is deleted. 
Please check this jsfiddle for that

> https://jsfiddle.net/d6ds7qL2/1/

When I add a html click handler inorder to change the confirm text to the original delete text,

> ```
> $('html').click(function(event){
>      if($('.confirmDelete').is(':visible')){
>          $('.confirmDelete').hide();
>          $('.deleteLink').show();
>          return false;
>      }
> });
> $('.confirmDelete').hide();
> $('.deleteLink').click(function (event) {
>     $(this).hide();
>     $('.confirmDelete').filter(':visible').each(function () {
>         $(this).hide();
>         $(this).prev('.deleteLink').show();
>     });
>     $(this).next('.confirmDelete').show();
>     event.stopPropagation();
>     return false;
> });
> ```
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/d6ds7qL2/2/

But the issue is now on clicking the 'Confirm' text it is not going to href but hiding the confirm text and showing the delete text.

Comment: Does my answer work for you buddy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to update the script and it is now working as intended

```js
$('html').click(function(e){
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(!target.hasClass('confirmDelete')){
        if($('.confirmDelete').is(':visible')){
            $('.confirmDelete').hide();
            $('.deleteLink').show();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
$('.confirmDelete').hide();
$('.deleteLink').click(function (event) {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.confirmDelete').filter(':visible').each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev('.deleteLink').show();
    });
    $(this).next('.confirmDelete').show();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="60%">file name 1</td>
        <td width="40%">
            <a class="deleteLink" href="#">Del</a>
            <a style="display:none;" class="confirmDelete" href="delete.html?file=1">Confirm?</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>file name 2</td>
        <td>
            <a class="deleteLink" href="#">Del</a>
            <a style="display:none;" class="confirmDelete" href="delete.html?file=2">Confirm?</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>file name 3</td>
        <td>
            <a class="deleteLink" href="#">Del</a>
            <a style="display:none;" class="confirmDelete" href="http://google.com?file=3">Confirm?</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>file name 4</td>
        <td>
            <a class="deleteLink" href="#">Del</a>
            <a style="display:none;" class="confirmDelete" href="http://google.com?file=4">Confirm?</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>file name 5</td>
        <td>
            <a class="deleteLink" href="#">Del</a>
            <a style="display:none;" class="confirmDelete" href="http://google.com?file=5">Confirm?</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of `html`, `document`.

```
$(document).not(".confirmDelete").click(function(event){
    if($('.confirmDelete').is(':visible')){
        $('.confirmDelete').hide();
        $('.deleteLink').show();
        return false;
    }
});
$('.confirmDelete').hide();
$('.deleteLink').click(function (event) {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.confirmDelete').filter(':visible').each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev('.deleteLink').show();
    });
    $(this).next('.confirmDelete').show();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/945j4g0x/**

Comment: This is similiar to the first js fiddle link that I have mentioned. I am using the html click, so that onclicking any other dom element the confirm goes back to the original delete text

Comment: @anoop.george Nopes, it doesn't.

Comment: in the jsfiddle that you have provided, when i click the 'Del' text it shows the 'Confirm?' but when i click the outside of the td the 'Confirm?' text does not go back to 'Del' . This is happening in my first jsfiddle link. In my second jsfiddle link this 'Confirm?' text goes back to 'Del' when I click anywhere else but on clicking the 'Confirm?' it does not take me to the actual delete link. So I am trying to achieve that

Comment: @anoop.george In the fiddle I have provided, clicking on Del, changes to confirm. Clicking outside, changes confirm to Del, click in confirm takes you to the link. Is that what you want?